What is Inline Frame in c++/VS?
I'm debugging some c++ code. In call stack I have calls with [Inline Frame] before them, what is that and how it's different from normal calls? I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (if you down voting then say why, if it's so trivial then answer, I couldn't find answer anywhere on the internet)

Just guessing, but perhaps a function that has been inlined by the compiler? Perhaps a browse through the VS2022 debugger documentation could help?

I don' t recall ever seeing this in my debugging sessions (mainly use vs2019 for production code) however a quick Google search leads to this information: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/debugger-step-over-steps-to-inlined-frame/176447

I suspect you are asking what inlining is?

Side note: Good on you for being a rare C++ newbie using the debugger. May you have a long and successful career.

Thanks I will check VS Debugger doc I forgot about this ‍♂️. I already found what inlining is before asking, but I don't think it's the same thing here. About newbie using debugger, I'm c++ newbie but I have years of professional experience in other languages (mainly C#)

I consider it should be inline function frame.
The document also mentions:

The GetStackTraceEx method provides inline frame support. For more
information about working with inline functions, see Debugging
Optimized Code and Inline Functions.

Sample: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Inconsistent-debug-information-for-inlin/10582059
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

__forceinline void test3(size_t len, set<double>& s) {
    s.insert(0.0);
    while (s.size() < len) {
        auto it = s.rbegin();
        double last = *it;
        s.insert(last + 1.0);
    }
}

__forceinline void test2(size_t len) {
    set <double> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        test3(len, s);
    }
    cout << "last: " << *(s.rbegin()) << " size: " << s.size() << endl;
}

__declspec(noinline) void test(size_t len) {
    test2(len);
}

#pragma optimize("", off)

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    test(1000000);
    return 0;
}

#pragma optimize("", on)

Compile  the code: cl source.cpp  /Zi /O2 /GL
[inline frame] appears to the left of functions test2 and test3.

Thanks, in my case not all calls with [Inline Frame] are from functions with any inline declaration but it's the best answer from what I can see.
